# Running a python script from inside a CDK stack?

Tags: python, flask, aws-cdk

I have an AWS CDK project with the following structure. The top `app.py` is simply the deafult CDK entry point, `my_Stack.py` is where the main Stack and Constructs live. The stack consists of static from the `site-staging` folder which is deployed to an S3 bucket and served with a CloudFront deployment.

```
project/
├── app.py
├── site_staging/
└── my_stack/
    ├── my_stack.py
    └── app/
        ├── app.py
        ├── Map.py
        └── freeze.py
```

The problem is that the static files are built using Frozen-Flask from a Flask app that lives in `my_stack/app/app.py`. Currently I have to manually invoke the static build from the `app` directory (e.g. `python freeze.py`).

What I want is to have the `my_stack.py` script run the `freeze.py` code when I deploy the stack with `cdk deploy`.

I have tried:

- moving the `freeze.py` code into `my_stack.py`  andimporting the flask `app` module directly, but then it can't find `Map.py` from the subfolder which it needs and can't find (`app.py` itself uses a simple `import Map`.)
- running it as a subprocess, which throws a 500 error that seems to be related to the Flask webserver not launching or binding to the right port

I've simplified things a bit for discussion, the repo is here https://github.com/anthonymobile/rna-dashboard